# Java Scanner nextLine Issue, additional enter is needed

Tags: java

I'm studying java I/O. There is some issue on my code.
I want to print

```
[0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1]
[2, 0, 1]
[10, 0, 5]
```

But additional enter is needed.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int tc = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println();

    for (int i = 0; i < tc; i++) {
        int line = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();

        for (int j = 0; j < line; j++) {
            System.out.println(i+""+j);
            int[] st = Arrays.stream(sc.nextLine().split(" "))
                    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(st));
        }
    }
}
```

Below is input & output. And I don't know why [10, 0, 5] is not shown. If I push enter key, then [10, 0, 5] appears.

```
Input
2
2
0 0 1
1 0 1
3
0 0 1
2 0 1
10 0 5

Output
[0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1]
[2, 0, 1]
(additional enter)
[10, 0, 5]
```

Comment: Can you explain the idea behind this code? What does `tc` mean?

Comment: @ernest_k not true. If you don't have it, the `nextLine` call immediately following a `nextInt` will return an empty string.

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank sorry, tc means test case.
2 at the top is tc.

Comment: So you want to 1) ask the user for the number of test cases, then 2) you collect these, each being an integer. Then what? What is the idea *in words*?

Comment: @ernest_k I think nextLine() after nextInt() is needed If I want to call nextLine().

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank sorry I'm not living in English culture. So.. I just want to print [0, 0, 1] [1, 0, 1] [0, 0, 1] [2, 0, 1] [10, 0, 5] without additional enter.

Comment: @AndyTurner Could I get any advice for this issue?

Comment: @user4235523 I cannot reproduce this behavior.

Comment: Try adding `System.out.flush();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read the java [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) for `nextLine` method.

> Since this method continues to search through the input looking for a
>   line separator, it may buffer all of the input searching for the line
>   to skip if no line separators are present.

This nextLine call blocks until it finds line seperator, which is the additional enter.

```
int[] st = Arrays.stream(sc.nextLine().split(" "))
                    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

Comment: Thx! I thought all examples include line seperator. But some of them include line seperator,  the others not. I figured it out now.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //your code is working as expected for given input after removing some print statements 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(Paths.get(System.in));
    int tc = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    //remove extra print statement 
    // System.out.println();

    for (int i = 0; i < tc; i++) {
        int line = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();

        for (int j = 0; j < line; j++) {
            //remove extra print statement                
            // System.out.println(i+""+j);
            int[] st = Arrays.stream(sc.nextLine().split(" ")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(st));
        }
    }
}
```